# clicker game upgrade isn't working it just takes all of the money away and doesn't upgrade

Tags: javascript, html

im making a marijuana clicker game, and i did something and i don't know wat i did but now it doesn't show the amount of any variable, and i cannot increase any variable, if anyone could find out what i did and tell me how to fix it i would appreciate it immensely

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
      var money=0;
      var moneyPC=1;
      var clickerupgrademoney = moneyPC*10;
      var drugdealers = 0;
      var weed = 0;
      var weedupgrade = 1;
      var weedupgrademoney = weedPC *10;
    
        
        function addMoney(){
          if(weed>0){
              money+=moneyPC;
              weed-=1;
          }
           
        }
      function upgrade1(){
        var showmoneypc = document.getElementById("clickupgrade");
        showmoneypc.innerHTML = moneyPC;
         if(money >= clickerupgrademoney){
            moneyPC+=1;
            money-=clickerupgrademoney;
        }
        else{
          alert("not enought cash");
        }
      }
      function buydrugdealer(){
        if(money >= drugdealers + 5 * 10){
          drugdealers ++;
          
        }
          else{
              alert()
          }
          var showdrug = document.getElementById("showdrugs");
          showdrug.innerHTML = drugdealers;
      }
      setInterval(function drugmoney(){
        money+=drugdealers*1;
      },500)
      function upgradeweed(){
          if(money>=)
      }
      setInterval(function updatemoney(){
          var cash = document.getElementById("showmoney");
          cash.innerHTML = money;
          var ganja = document.getElementById("grow");
          ganja.innerHTML = weed;
      })
      
      function growweed(){
          weed += weedupgrade;
      }
      
        
      
      
    </script>
    <style>
      p{
        border-radius:3px;
        font-size:20px;
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ff8800;
        font-family: helvetica;
      }
      h1{
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        color: #ff8800;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      button{
        position: relative;
        left: 50px;
        background: background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#888, #555);
        background-color: #333333;
        color: #ccc;
        margin: 20px auto;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        border: 0 none;
        border-radius: 6px;
        
      }
      body{
        background-color: #191919;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>clicker game</title>
  </head>
  <h1>
    Aquire
  </h1>
  <p id="showmoney">
  </p>
  <body>
 <button id="click" onClick="addMoney()">
      sell weed
    </button>
      <p id="grow">0</p>
      <button onClick="growweed()">grow weed</button>
    <h1>
      Upgrade
    </h1>
    <p id="clickupgrade">
      0
    </p>
    <button id="clickupgradebutton" onClick="upgrade1()">
      upgrade selling
    </button>
      <p id="showweedupgrade">0</p>
      <button onClick="upgradeweed">upgrade growing</button>
      <p id="showdrugs">0</p>
      <button onClick="buydrugdealer()">buy drug dealer</button>
    <p id="insufficentfunds">
        
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `i did something and i don't know wat i did` - source control? compare to previous version? then you'll see "wat u did" - do you get any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: Well, the first issue you may want to address is `Uncaught ReferenceError: growweed is not defined` your have an error in your code snippet

Comment: i get an error saying that the js functions are not defined in HTMLElement.onClick

Comment: `weedPC` doesn't exist, and `if(money>=)` use the console view and actually try to see what is wrong with your code..

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: addMoney is not defined and weedPC doesn't exist.

Try wrapping your functions in a window.onload();

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error in

```
      function upgradeweed(){
          if(money>=)
      }
```

You need something after the >=.

Also, the CSS has a problem with the repeated background:

`background: background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#888, #555);`

You can see these kinds of errors by going into the developer console. When I do that in my Chrome browser I see this:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

This will have a link with it that you can click to see the error in your code.